# Differentiate $v(x,y)=-\int_0^x u_y(t,0)dt+\int_0^y u_x (x,t) dt$ w.r.t. $x,y$ to prove complex differentiability

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, complex-integration

> The domain is an **open unit box** (if required) and $u$ is harmonic, $v$ is harmonic conjugate defined below. Prove Complex Differentiabilty

Diffirentiate with respect to $x$ and $y$:

$$v(x,y)=-\int_0^x u_y(t,0)dt+\int_0^y u_x (x,t) dt$$

I assumed the answer would be:

$v_x=-u_y$ and $v_y=u_x$ (which would imply complex differentiability using Cauchy Riemann), but can somebody help me do the differentiation explicitly, with explanations?

I tried using $dv/dx=dv/dt \times dt/dx$

If I'm correct $dv/dt=-u_y(x,0)+u_x(x,y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v(x,y)$ be given by

$$v(x,y)=-\int_0^x u_y(t,0)\,dt+\int_0^y u_x (x,t)\, dt$$

Then, taking the partial derivative with respect to $x$ yields

$$\begin{align}
v_x(x,y)&=-u_y(x,0)+\int_0^y u_{xx} (x,t) \,dt \tag 1\\\\
&=-u_y(x,0)-\int_0^y u_{yy} (x,t) \,dt \tag 2\\\\
&=-u_y(x,0)-\left(u_y(x,y)-u_y(x,0)\right)\\\\
&=-u_y(x,y)
\end{align}$$

which is a Cauchy-Riemann equation.  Note in going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we exploited the fact that $u$ is harmonic.

Then, taking the derivative with respect to $y$ yields

$$v_y(x,y)=u_x(x,y)$$

which is the other Cauchy-Riemann equation.  And we are done!

Comment: thanks a lot, this cleared things up :)

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: I tried computing $v_y$ by the same logic, and I get: $v_y(x,y)=-\int_0^x u_{yy}(t,0)dt+ u_{x} (x,y)=\int_0^x u_{xx}(t,0)dt+u_{x} (x,y)=u_x (x,0)-u_x(0,0)+u_x(x,y)$                                                                                         . This implies that $u_x (x,0)-u_x(0,0)=0$

Comment: Note that the first integral $-\int_0^x u_y(t,0)\,dt$ does not depend on $y$.  So, in taking the partial with respect to $y$, the only term is $u_x(x,y)$.

Comment: You're quite welcome!

Comment: Mark Viola, how did you get $\int_0^y u_{yy} (x,t) \,dt = u_y(x,y)-u_y(x,0)$ ? This is practically my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2895737). The thing is your seems to be integrating with respect to dt but somehow you got rid one partial of $y$. There's probably something about how $t$ is just a dummy for $y$, but I don't see how to do this precisely. Please help.